# Foreign keys and serializers in django rest

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_type = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    creation_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)


class Allergie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="X")


class PatientAllergies(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name="patient_allergies", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    allergie = models.ForeignKey(Allergie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    professional_contract = models.ForeignKey(ProfessionalContract, null=True ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Is it possible to retrieve a patient objecto with a property that is a list of all his allergies, including name and id with these models?

Answer (score 0):

you have the PatientAllergies as a chain,
so

```
patientAllergies = PatientAllergies.objects.get(patient.id_number='0000')
patientAllergies.allergie #you get the single allergie model connect with it, take care it is a foreignKey so it is singolar and not many
patientAlleriges.patient.user #will give you access to all the data of the user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) like so:

```
Patient.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('patient_allergies__allergie', to_attr='allergies')
)
```

**EDIT**: Just learned that `to_attr` will not work on multiple levels of prefetch. Another approach I can think of is use a model property for `Patient` that returns its related allergies like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    @property
    def allergies(self):
        return Allergie.objects.filter(patientallergies_set__patient=self)
```

Then in your serializer, the `allergies` field can use the `Allergies` serializer

Comment: this works, but now I have trouble trying to use Serializers with it.

Comment: It turns out it doesn't work, it says my object patient has no attribute allergies